# ASP.net LinkButtion if then else

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, linkbutton, commandargument

Hey all i have this piece of code here:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") & "|" & Eval("theName")%>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("status")%>' CommandName='<%#Eval("status")%>' ID="statusLink" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And where it says "status" it would either be "REJECTED", "PENDING" or "APPROVED". The problem being is that how can i not have a link if it says **APPROVED** but have different links for the **REJECTED** and **APPROVED**?

I check the clicks this way currently:

```
Protected Sub grdView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdView.RowCommand
    Dim command As String = e.CommandName.ToString
    Dim theName() As String = Split(e.CommandArgument.ToString, "|")
    Dim cid As String = theName(0)

    If cid.Length <= 0 Then Exit Sub

    Select Case command
        Case "PENDING"
            Response.Redirect("/account/Req.aspx?ID=" & cid & "&ACCEPT=yes&NAME=" & theName(1))
        Case "REJECTED"
            Response.Redirect("/account/Req.aspx?ID=" & cid & "&ACCEPT=no&NAME=" & theName(1))
    End Select
End Sub
```

So if one records was like this:

```
 Bob | Barker | Bob@priceisright.com | PENDING (Approve | Reject)
```

Then the user would have the choice to either Approve or reject that person by pressing either link.

If it was approved already then it should just look like this:

```
 Bob | Barker | Bob@priceisright.com | Approve!
```

...without being linked with anything.

Any help would be great!

**UPDATE**

Maybe a better alternative to this is to just create the asp linkbuttons dynamically. But how would u insert them into the correct spot on the page?

Comment: You kow that even VB.NET is case-sensitive when strings are compared? You say the status caan be _"Pending"_ but you're checking for _"PENDING"_. A typo?

Answer (score 1):

Quick, very quick workaround - but it doens't take care of not showing the link as simple text when it's approved, is something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton 
     OnClientClick='<%#Eval("status")=="Approved"?"javascript:return false;":""%>'
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") & "|" & Eval("theName")%>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("status")%>' CommandName='<%#Eval("status")%>' ID="statusLink" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

What that does is that disables the form submission when the status is approved by returning false from the Javascript function call. Otherwise, it posts backs to the server.

**Update:**

Here's the complete solution, making the "Approved" link buttons displaying text only; without posting back or hyperlink:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton 
     name='<%#Eval("status") %>'
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") & "|" & Eval("theName")%>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("status")%>' CommandName='<%#Eval("status")%>' ID="statusLink" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, you can simply call a JS function on Window.load to remove all the `hrefs` from elements with name `Approved`

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {    
        //get elements with name Approved
        var aprovedLinks = document.getElementsByName("Approved");
        for (var i = 0; i < aprovedLinks.length; i++) {
            //remove the hyperlink
            aprovedLinks[i].removeAttribute("href", 0);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, lcarus. However, if the text was **REJECTED** **(without a link)** and i needed to place **(Approve)** next to it **(with a link)** so that they can above them then how would i modify the code above to do that?

Comment: Update OP with another alternative way.